# Set index in pandas df without creating duplicate column

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

My dataframe looks like this:

```
In [120]: data.head()
Out[120]: 
         date   open   high    low  close  volume
0  2017-08-07  2.276  2.276  2.253  2.257     0.0
1  2017-08-08  2.260  2.291  2.253  2.283     0.0
2  2017-08-09  2.225  2.249  2.212  2.241     0.0
3  2017-08-10  2.241  2.241  2.210  2.212     0.0
4  2017-08-11  2.199  2.222  2.182  2.189     0.0
```

after doing:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
```

I end up with this:

```
In [122]: data.head()
Out[122]: 
                  date   open   high    low  close  volume
date                                                      
2017-08-07  2017-08-07  2.276  2.276  2.253  2.257     0.0
2017-08-08  2017-08-08  2.260  2.291  2.253  2.283     0.0
2017-08-09  2017-08-09  2.225  2.249  2.212  2.241     0.0
2017-08-10  2017-08-10  2.241  2.241  2.210  2.212     0.0
2017-08-11  2017-08-11  2.199  2.222  2.182  2.189     0.0
```

how can i avoid ending up with a duplicate date column? Grateful for your help. (Pandas 0.21.1)

Comment: Use `df = df.set_index('date')`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert to date first and use `.set_index()`:

```
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
data.set_index('date', inplace=True)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
             open   high    low  close  volume
date                                          
2017-08-07  2.276  2.276  2.253  2.257     0.0
2017-08-08  2.260  2.291  2.253  2.283     0.0
2017-08-09  2.225  2.249  2.212  2.241     0.0
2017-08-10  2.241  2.241  2.210  2.212     0.0
2017-08-11  2.199  2.222  2.182  2.189     0.0
```

`inplace=True` modifies your `data` instead of creating a new dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using drop instead of inplace. Works too.

data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])

**data.set_index('date', drop=True)**

When you set drop property to True, it delete the column to be used as the new index